# How to change Visual Source Safe username

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Is it possible to change the username of a VSS user?

My Windows login name (same as VSS name) has recently been changed, but not been updated within the VSS database. No passwords have been changed.

Now, when I try to log in to VSS with my old username it says 'Invalid Password', and if I try using my new username it says **User "*myUsername*" not found**

Can this be updated via the GUI or will I have to hack around in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new user in the VSS data base and after that you can use VSS Import Tool to import data from the old one.

See [Kevin Gao's blog entry on VSS](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe/new-import-vss-to-sourceanywhere-tool.html).

Comment: OK, thanks for that - I figured it might have to involve creating a new account somewhere. As it happens, I managed to get the old account working again with a new password, but have marked as answer nonetheless!